# Is it insane to store access token in shelve object?

Tags: python, authentication, caching, fastapi, shelve

My friends and I are making a project to study programming. It consists of several microservices. For our main microservice we use Redis to store auth tokens and it works great.

But we needed another FastAPI microservice which would be extremely small (basically auth and a couple API endpoints). Very very simple. This is why I though that adding Redis as a dependency to it would be overkill. We still need database, so we have Postgres.

Now, I need to store access tokens somewhere, and they have to expire automatically after an hour. I can either make a trigger to delete expired tokens (which is advised against because triggers are hard to test and maintain) or make a cron-job.

I didn't like those options so I decided to store tokens in shelve. I also made a wrapper that deletes token when trying to retrieve it if it expired.

```
import shelve

from dal.utils import timezone_aware_now


class ShelveDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        self._db = shelve.open("shelve_store", "c")

    def get(self, key):
        token = self._db.get(key, None)
        if token is None:
            return None

        if token["expire"] < timezone_aware_now():
            del self._db[key]
            return self.get(key)

        return token

    def update(self, key, value):
        self._db[key] = value
        return True

    def delete(self, key):
        del self._db[key]
        return True

    def close(self):
        self._db.close()


cache_driver = ShelveDriver()
```

It works, but I strongly feel that this is wrong approach. Please, point out any flaws you can find in this. Thank you!

Comment: Since a shelve is local to the current instance; what happens if you want to run more instances? If you're running this in a container; how are you handling restarts of the container? Any reason why you can't use a JWT if you want to use authentication across many services and don't want to store anything local? If you already have Postgres, why not use it if you need persistent storage instead of shelve?

Comment: Didn't consider running several instances. It's a valid point, thank  you @MatsLindh